# ClassNotFound Exception in Spark Scala Code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I have used maven project in Scala. I have used all dependencies in pom.

Still I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` when I run `spark-submit` command.

`clean compile assembly:single` is the Maven goal which I used.

Following is the spark submit command I have used.

```
spark-submit --class com.SimpleScalaApp.SimpleApp --master local /location/file.jar
```

Comment: Do you see the class file inside the JAR? `jar tvf /location/file.jar`

Comment: @philantrovert , I am checking that. Am I right in terms of maven goal which I specified. I am using hbase spark connector here and spark dependencies.

Comment: `assembly:single` will give you a fat JAR, I think. If that's what you want then you're good.

Comment: Yes. When we are using some dependencies , we have to make fat jar. Is it so?

Comment: Depends. If the dependencies are available in the classpath at runtime then you don't. If not, adding it to your Project's jar (by creating a far jar) is an option.

Comment: I have tried that command tar tvf , it has done some processing. But I could not see any folder or file created at that location

Comment: @philantrovert I changed jar extension to zip , Inside scala folder, I can not see SimpleApp.class file

Comment: Your code is not getting compiled. Please use a Scala compiler in your pom.xml

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354934/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-scala Keep googling.

Comment: Could you please tell where will I see class file and what will be name of classFile?

Comment: As per the above link: I have used these dependencies:
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.11.5</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
  </properties>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
   <version>2.10.4</version>
  </dependency>
along with spark core dependencies.Still its failing

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no useful comment on the question in my opinion. The ClassNotFoundException mostly is thrown when version of your dependencies are not match together.

First of all it's better to check if all your dependencies are matched by checking those dependencies' pom files and consequently their usage order in the main project pom file.

A short description about the best practice of running the program on spark cluster is using shaded or assembly build form.

Comment: Those comments were useful @epcpu. The solution worked.