# How to run Main method in Scala in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am trying to get a main method to run in Scala in Intellij, but it is not working, and I don't know why.

File structure looks like this...

```
.
├── cse116.iml
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── Main.scala
└── target
    └── classes
```

Main.scala looks like this...

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

When I try to do "Run" on Intellij, I get the following error:

Error: Could not find or load main class Main

I am not sure what configuration is messed up. What may be some common reasons for this happening?

Comment: Could you please add your pom.xml?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354934/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-scala

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running a recent version of intelliJ, have the Scala plugin installed and your dependencies for Scala is correct in your pom file. You should see a tiny green arrow either on the left hand side of your main class or when right clicking within that class. Also, if you are on macOS there is the `ctrl+shift+r` to run the file as shown in the image below.

If that is not the case, consider creating a new Scala project from the IDE itself. You'd then choose an `sbt` project. `sbt` is the equivalent of `maven` in the Scala world. This one "should" work, if it doesn't it is very likely to give you a better Scala specific error message(s)

[image: Run command in intelliJ]